# Spring Security ExceptionTranslationFilter throw "Unable to handle the Spring Security Exception because the response is already committed."

Tags: servlets, spring-security, tomcat8, servletexception

I'm using spring security web 5.0.9 and tomcat 8.  ExceptionTranslationFilter throw ServletException  "Unable to handle the Spring Security Exception because the response is already committed."
I dig into the source code and find the root cause. I'm not sure whether it is a bug for spring security.

1. I throw the UsernameNotFoundException in AuthenticationUserDetailsService.loadUserDetails
2. SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler.onAuthenticationFailure catch the exception and then call

```
public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        if (defaultFailureUrl == null) {
            logger.debug("No failure URL set, sending 401 Unauthorized error");

            response.sendError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(),
                HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.getReasonPhrase());
        }
```

the sendError will set response committed to true, see ResponseFacade.java:

```
    public void sendError(int sc, String msg)
        throws IOException {
        ...
        response.setAppCommitted(true);
        ...

    }
```

3. Then ExceptionTranslationFilter catch it and check the response commit status, found it's true and then throw the exception

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
    ...
    if (response.isCommitted()) {
      throw new ServletException("Unable to handle the Spring Security Exception because the response is already committed.", ex);
    ...
}
```

4. nobody catch the ServletException and the application try to find the  /web_framework/error_page/405.html

I find the spring security code is changed in this bug fix https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/5273.

How to deal with the ServletException and return the valid 401 response, but not web_framework/error_page/405.html

Comment: Could you provide a Github sample - what is the simplest way to reproduce this issue? Generally, if the `SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler` is invoked, then the `ExceptionTranslationFilter` is not also invoked since there is no further response handling required.

Comment: tks for you tips， I found that the old code add SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler manually, I remove it, and it works now

Comment: Hey, that's great! I've gone ahead and added that as an answer below so that it is easier to find for folks that run into the same kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it could be a misconfiguration in the code.

Typically, if the `SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler` is invoked, then the `ExceptionTranslationFilter` is not also invoked since there is no further response handling required.